# Return values consisting of the set in Posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlc

I use https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc to generate code. I want to return human_id using the group_id array.

```
-- name: HumansByGroupID :many
SELECT human_id FROM groups
WHERE group_id IN (UNNEST($1::uuid[]));
```

return
`ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE (SQLSTATE 0A000)`

In my understanding, `... IN (UNNEST($1::uuid[]));` turns into `IN ('...','...','...');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```sql
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT col FROM UNNEST($1::uuid[]) AS col);
```

or, alternatively, you can also do:

```sql
WHERE group_id = ANY ($1::uuid[]);
```